# How to export object with transparency from Blender Internal?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I'm making a photo frame with glass on top of a emissive photo material. I get the desired output when I render. But when I export it as fbx or obj there is no transparency of glass neither is the photo emissive.

Comment: what are you trying to export? obj is an object format, it knows nothing about the glass material. Chances are that whatever you are exporting to will not be able to use the BL material either.

Comment: I'm trying to export a photo frame made by me with textures and materials as in fbx format. But the materials with transparency and emission do not get exported in Blender Internal. Why is that so? Plz help.

Comment: Basically my photo frame has 3 materials with 3 textures, each for one material. The frame has a simple diffuse image texture which is exporting properly as fbx. But the other two materials, one with glass texture with transparency and the other with image texture with emit are not exporting properly. The textures are missing in both the cases. I'm using Blender Render not Cycles. Plz help.

Comment: If you have more information to add, please use the [edit] link below your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are going to export to .fbx, you should only use Principled BSDF. In that case you cannot use mirror shader, or something like this on your scene. You have to use alpha channel...

If someone have a better solution, plz tell us!